# Números acima de 32, 64 bits

Tags: python

Como trabalhar com números acima de 32, 64 bits? A ideia está em gerar um números pseudo aleatórios grandes de até 4096, por exemplo, por um gerador de números pseudoaleatórios que gere números de 32.

Em C eu poderia alocar um espaço correspondente, trabalhando e colocando os números lá. Em Python pensei em usar array, mas preciso que o número final se torne um só. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar do módulo random em Python ser bem prático, para fins de criptografia a recomendação é usar a chamada `os.urandom()`, que tem aleatoridade mais garantida pelo sistema operacional.

Por outro lado é até mais conveniente, por que o `os.urandom` já aceita um parâmetro com o número de bytes aleatórios e devolve um objeto do tipo bytes - no caso, para 4096 bits, você usa `os.urandom(512)` - em geral para qualquer uso que você for fazer o objeto bytes vai ser mais prático do que um inteiro com 4096 bits.

No entanto, a linguagem suporta números inteiros desse tamanho - então se você desejar o valor numérico pode fazer: `int.from_bytes(os.urandom(512), "big")`. Se preferir como uma string de texto com 2 dígitos hexadecimais por byte, pode fazer `os.urandom(512).hex()` (convertível de volta para bytes com `bytes.fromhex(minha_string)` ).

Agora, vamos supor que você tenha outra função de sua preferência que gere números aleatórios de 32 bits, de tamanho fixo (por exemplo, uma chamada a um driver de um dispositivo de harware gerador de números aleatórorios) - nesse caso, você pode usar o módulo "struct" do Python para juntar 16 chamadas à sua função num objeto bytes contínuo com 512 bytes (e aí pode transformar em inteiro, ou em ma string hexadecimal, como acima):

`struct.pack("=16I", *(random.randrange(0, 2**32) for _ in range(16)))`

(No caso eu usei o random.randrange  como exemplo, mas a recomendação é realmente usar os.urandom, como expliquei acima). Entendendo essa expressão:
é uma chamada à função `struct.pack` onde  o primeiro parâmetro descreve os próximos: mais 16 inteiros de 32 bits que serão interpretados usando a *endiannes* nativa da máquina - little endian em x86_64 - indicado pelo sinal de "=". Em seguida uma generator expression que é desdobrada pelo operador `*` - cada elemento gerado é passado para a função como um parâmetro posicional. A expressão por sua vez simplemente repete 16 vezes, indicadas no `for _ in range(16)` a chamada a função desejada.

Answer (score 4):

Complementando um pouco a resposta do @Pedro, neste momento não existe valor limite para inteiros. Consegue ver isso pela [citação na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers):

> The sys.maxint constant was removed, since there is no longer a limit
>   to the value of integers

Traduzindo:

> A constante sys.maxint foi removida, pois já não existe um limite para valores inteiros

Imaginemos que teria algo correspondente a `2^4096` para guardar. Então isso seria perfeitamente calculável em python:

```
>>> 2**4096
1044388881413152506691752710716624382579964249047383780384233483283953907971557456848826811934997558340890106714439262837987573438185793607263236087851365277945956976543709998340361590134383718314428070011855946226376318839397712745672334684344586617496807908705803704071284048740118609114467977783598029006686938976881787785946905630190260940599579453432823469303026696443059025015972399867714215541693835559885291486318237914434496734087811872639496475100189041349008417061675093668333850551032972088269550769983616369411933015213796825837188091833656751221318492846368125550225998300412344784862595674492194617023806505913245610825731835380087608622102834270197698202313169017678006675195485079921636419370285375124784014907159135459982790513399611551794271106831134090584272884279791554849782954323534517065223269061394905987693002122963395687782878948440616007412945674919823050571642377154816321380631045902916136926708342856440730447899971901781465763473223850267253059899795996090799469201774624817718449867455659250178329070473119433165550807568221846571746373296884912819520317457002440926616910874148385078411929804522981857338977648103126085903001302413467189726673216491511131602920781738033436090243804708340403154190336L
```

[Veja este pequeno exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/SfSsF0)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randint(0, 2**64)
6502449964907846195
```

O Python cuida automaticamente de números grandes, e você não precisa se preocupar com o valor máximo em bits de um inteiro de 32 ou 64 bits.

Comment: Certo. Mas eu preciso criar através de alguns algoritmos para efeito de estudos sobre eles. Por exemplo, vou usar 3 algoritmos: Park-Miller, Xorshfit, Linear Congruential Generator. Usando estes 3 algoritmos tenho que ser capaz de gerar um número muito grande.